# db_query complete Content Type with all fields automatically

Tags: 7, database

Can I do this automatically in my module without hard coding the list of content type fields:

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$query->join(ALL FIELDS OF THIS CONTENT TYPE, FIELD ALIASES, ONs);
$query->fields('n', array('nid', 'title'))
    ->condition('n.status', 1)
    ->condition('n.type', 'airports_fs');
$query->addField(NODE.VALUES,  THESE CONTENT TYPE FIELDS);
    ->condition(EACH FIELD.deleted)
    ->condition(EACH FIELD.entity_type, 'node')
$query->addExpression(MY OWN CUSTOM EXPRESSION);
$result = $query->execute();
```

I'm open to any syntax - db_select, db_query, extenders, ? - as long as it's dynamic.

Comment: Hello :-) It's hard to analyse what is the expected outcome of above query.. Can you explain what you are trying to achieve using above query ?

Comment: @AnilSagar, I want the complete content type as i've set it up in the CMS - with all custom fields such as geo coordinates, descriptions, etc.. - in an associative array. does that make sense?

Comment: basically i'm trying to do `select * from airport_fs`. but that doesn't exist. every field of my content type - airport_fs - is stored in a relational table that still needs it's on conditions applied to relate to the content type entity.

Comment: Can you try using Entity field queries ? For more details https://drupal.org/node/1343708

Comment: @AnilSagar, i'm was just looking at that and it look very close, but not clear if `addExpression` can be used with `EntityFieldQuery()`. More specifically i want to selelct/sort by distance from the current user's lon/lat coordinates.

Comment: @EliATaylor There's no `addExpression()`, but you can use `addTag()` to tag the query, and implement `hook_query_TAG_alter()` to tack `addExpression()` on before it gets executed

Comment: @Clive, thank you very much also! this worked to get my expression included, but the `EntityFieldQuery()->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')->entityCondition('bundle', 'airports_fs')` still only returns  '_nid_', '_vid_', and '_type_'. How do i get a `select *` on the whole bundle?

Comment: @Clive, can the `EntityFieldQuery` return all bundled fields to avoid the additional call of `node_load(array_keys($nearest['node']))`?

Comment: It can't, it just loads up the IDs. You can use `node_load_multiple` to save some overhead if there are multiple nodes though